# nth child anchor issue

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a page which brings database entries in and displays them, and i have given every other entry/listing this style:

```
hjl:nth-child(odd) { background: #F2F2F2;}
```

And this is my HTML/PHP

```
<a href="paging.php?job_id=<?php echo $rsjobinfo['job_id'];?>">
<div class = "hjl">
<div class = "hjldate">
<p>Posted on:<br /><?php echo $date = date('d M Y', strtotime($rsjobinfo['date']));?></p>
</div>      
<div class = "hjljobinfo">
<h1><?php echo $rsjobinfo['job_title'];?></h1>
<h2><?php echo $rsjobinfo['company_name'];?> |</h2>
<p class = "location"><?php echo $rsjobinfo['city'];?>, <?php echo $rsjobinfo['county'];?>, <?php echo $rsjobinfo['country'];?></p>
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

However, when i try to wrap each entire entry in an anchor tag, every entry changes to the background style listed above, no longer recognising the 'odd'.

This is the HTMl that's generated:

```
<a href="paging.php?job_id=253">
<div class = "hjl">                 
  <div class = "hjldate">
    <p>Posted on:<br />11 Jul 2011</p>
  </div>

  <div class = "hjljobinfo">
    <h1>Entry One</h1>
<h2>Company |</h2>
<p class = "location">New York, NY, USA</p>
 </div>

</div>
</a>
```

I'm not used to using nth-child so i'm not sure how to fix it (i've tried playing around with adding an 'a' to the above but its not making any difference).

Does anyone have any pointers they can kick me towards?

Thanks
Dan

Comment: It's `:nth-child()`, not `.nth-child()`. Pseudo-classes are marked by colons. Can you show us the HTML that's generated by your PHP code?

Comment: @BoltClock Hi BC, just done so :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:nth-child` works between siblings [<sup>documentation</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo). That means that the counter (*`odd` in this case*) applies to elements with the same parent.

If you wrap each `.hjl` in a `a` then they no longer share the same parent so the selector tries to find *odd* `.hjl` elements inside the `a` element and finds just the first one (the only one that exists in the `a`).

So, you should change your selector to work with `a` tags (*perhaps apply a `class` as well for more precision*)

---

on another note, placing `div` and `h1/h2` elements inside a `a` tag is invalid and will cause other issues.

Comment: Ahh, ok that almost makes sense to me. Is there a fix Gaby?

Comment: Yeah i don't like doing it but i quite want the entire element to be the link. I've tried using buttons instead but i just don't like them as much

Comment: @Dan, targeting the `a` is the fix instead of the `.hjl`, **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/CAnRj/)**

Comment: Thanks Gaby, much appreciated. I 'll give that a try and see what other issues i run into with the anchor being invalid. Thanks again, Dan

Answer (score 1):

You need to add ":" right in front of it, like so:

```
YourElement:nth-child( { number expression | odd | even } ) {
declaration block
}
```

Your element is something like tr, li, or anything like that. Hope that helps.

Comment: @BennyTija Hi Benny, sorry, i do have that, i just stripped it out of the above (added now with edit). Sorry about that.

Comment: @Dan: It seems you used "." instead of colon ":". and also, it seems that it colors all the child with your css background color because you made a wrong child selection, therefore it colors everything inside your child div.